# Apache Superset upgrade fails to use the same connection strings

Tags: sql-server, apache-superset, pymssql

I've been using Apache Superset for several months now. I do have a 2.0.1 instance with mssql installed that is capable of connecting to this connection string:

```
mssql+pymssql://DBUSER:STDPASS@myorg.org:1433/TESTDAT@BASE$
```

What I want to illustrate with this connection string is that everything looks ok except for the name of the DB, that has some special characters. I have read this could be an issue if it was a password but in this case it connects completely fine.

In a newer instance (3.0.1) of Superset, installed in the same server as the previously described one, the same connection string returns an error like:

> ERROR: Either the username "DBUSER", password, or database name "TESTDAT@BASE$" is incorrect.

I could downgrade this instance, but I feel like something very small has changed in the underlying sqlAlchemy version that I'm missing

Thanks in advance!

I've tried scaping the characters of the DBNAME using urllib but it was unsuccesful. I did also tried adding the keyword /?Encrypt=yes at the end of the connection string as the documentation suggest, but it raises an error saying that it is a unexpected keyword argument.

Comment: From memory `mssql+pymssql://` uses FreeTDS under the covers... do you have a `[myorg.org:1433]` section registered in your [`freetds.conf` file](https://www.freetds.org/userguide/freetdsconf.html)? Is it using the correct `tds version` for the target server? FreeTDS being involved is probably why you got the unexpected keyword argument error, too - that's the `encryption` parameter in the file.